# Python 3: Tkinter Text Autocompletion does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to translate the `auto-completion` for the `Entry` widget from this website:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/

Into my `Python 3 Tkinter` code. Unfortunately that version was written in `Python 2`, and uses the `Entry` widget instead of the `Text` widget.

I get the following error though:

```
  File "C:\Users\henrydavidzhu\Desktop\Arshi\beta-development\tab_test.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.var = self["textvariable"]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1272, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-textvariable"
```

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar()

        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)

        self.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.up)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.down)

        self.lb_up = False

        self.keywords = ['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else',
        'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is',
        'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with',
        'yield']

    def changed(self, name, index, mode):  

        if self.var.get() == '':
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
        else:
            words = self.comparison()
            if words:            
                if not self.lb_up:
                    self.lb = Listbox()
                    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height())
                    self.lb_up = True

                self.lb.delete(0, END)
                for w in words:
                    self.lb.insert(END,w)
            else:
                if self.lb_up:
                    self.lb.destroy()
                    self.lb_up = False

    def selection(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            self.var.set(self.lb.get(ACTIVE))
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
            self.icursor(END)

    def up(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != '0':                
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)-1)                
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def down(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != END:                        
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)+1)        
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def comparison(self):
        pattern = re.compile('.*' + self.var.get() + '.*')
        return [w for w in self.lista if re.match(pattern, w)]

class Arshi(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.createtext()

    def createtext(self):
        text = CustomText(self)
        text.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Arshi")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Arshi(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is Entry widgets may have a textvariable and Text widgets don't. The reason is most like that Entry widgets are designed to allow the user see and modify a _single_ line of text, whereas Text widgets are for handling multiple lines. For that reason it's not even clear what autocompletion means in such a context (because, for example, a down-arrow key press would conventionally be expected to move the cursor down one line in the multiple lines displayed).

Comment: @martineau So it's impossible?

Comment: Yes, probably — `Text` widgets are very versatile. It's unclear how one would mimic the automatic updating feature of an associated `StringVar` however. You would also need to resolve the is of how you'd want autocompletion to be invoked (and still allow the text cursor to be moved). Instead of autocompletion, maybe you should consider something like hot-keys or macros. Regardless, the techniques used in the Activestate recipe _are_ applicable, should you want to attempt to do it.

Comment: What is your actual question? are you asking us to rewrite the code for you?

Comment: @martineau: Autocomplete is definitely _not_ impossible. Everything you need is available in the widget. It's just that you have to do all of the work yourself.

Comment: @Bryan: You're indeed correct. The response in my previous comment was phrased improperly because I was thinking the OP had just asked "Is it possible?". Beyond explaining the cause of the problem, my main point was simply that the way autocomplete worked in the recipe likely wouldn't make as much sense — nor be of much value — in a multiline `Text` subclass.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think I almost have it done. I just am having trouble figuring out where to place it. I have to get the position of the last character in the tkinter.